# MSSQL pyodbc insert failing due to range of computer representation (8 bytes)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Can someone help me how to insert"OI-9786E543971246B29470AFA10414A1E2" value as a string to MSSQL db in python?

Error I get is:
`"pyodbc.DataError: ('22003', "[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The floating point value '9786E' is out of the range of computer representation (8 bytes)."`

```
        for client in clients:
            counts += 1
            insert_stmt += f"INSERT INTO [x].[dbo].[x] ([commcell],[clientName],[clientDisplayName],[clientHostName],[instanceId]) VALUES ('{client['commcell']}','{client['clientName']}','{client['clientDisplayName']}','{client['clientHostName']}','{client['instanceId']}') \r\n"
            if counts % 300 == 0:
                insert_stmt += "COMMIT TRANSACTION"
                cursor.execute(insert_stmt)
                cursor.commit()
                insert_stmt = "BEGIN TRANSACTION \r\n"
        if insert_stmt != "BEGIN TRANSACTION \r\n":
            insert_stmt += "COMMIT TRANSACTION"
            cursor.execute(insert_stmt)
            cursor.commit()
```

So basically if I would to remove **OI-** at the front of the value it would be ok..

Type of the value is string.
Tried column types in MSSQL to be as varchar(max), nvarchar(max), text and so on.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to include your existing attempt in your question. My guess, you're *injecting* the value.

Comment: Hi @ThomA - yes, it's a INSERT. Edited the post.

Comment: `The floating point value '9786E'` that's not a floating point value. Unless you used concatenation of strings to construct the SQL query. Imagine what would happen if the value was `'; DROP TABLE STUDENT;--` instead. That's how SQL injection attacks happen

Comment: *"It's a INSERT"* isn't your code... Again, you're probably using injection, which means that a value like `OI-9786E543971246B29470AFA10414A1E2` is interpreted as the expression "Column `OI` *minus* the `float` value `9786E543971246` and, oh that's not a valid `float`, it's too big. **Error**"

Comment: The code almost certainly is *not* using pyodbc properly. Instead of passing parameters, it concatenations strings and probably doesn't even quote them. If you write `VALUES (OI-9786E543971246B29470AFA10414A1E2)` what is the server supposed to do? That looks like a subtraction, probably involving a column, and what looks like a number in scientific notation `9786E543971246`, ie `9786*10^543971246`

Comment: @ThomA - updated with code snippet. Do you have any advise how should I do that, to insert such value?

Comment: *"`VALUES ('{client['commcell']}','{client['clientName']}',...`"* And we have a "winner", *injection*; a fatal and significant security flaw. **Parametrise** your code and this problem goes away.

Comment: @ThomA thanks for your opinion. Could you share a example of a parametrised insert  then? How it should look?

Comment: What are you using? PyODBC? There's an [example of an `INSERT` in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16#insert-a-row) that uses parameters and warns about injection.

Comment: *"thanks for your opinion"* It's not an opinion; Injection *is* a very well known, and significant, security flaw that has existed and been known about for *decades*. It's been the result of countless breaches over the years, due to poor development practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By concatenating strings this way you're causing a SQL injection attack against your own code.

The [Insert a row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16#insert-a-row) in SQL Server's [proof-of-concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16) tutorial shows how to safely pass values to any SQL query, not just INSERTs against SQL Server:

```
#Sample insert query
sql="""
INSERT INTO SalesLT.Product (Name, ProductNumber, StandardCost, ListPrice, SellStartDate) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"""

count = cursor.execute(sql,
'SQL Server Express New 20', 'SQLEXPRESS New 20', 0, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).rowcount
cnxn.commit()
print('Rows inserted: ' + str(count))
```

I modified the example a bit to make it clear that the SQL query *doesn't* include any values. This isn't a format string either. The parameter values never become part of the query itself. They're sent to the database server and used only after the query gets compiled into an execution plan.

At the very least, the python code should change to this:

```
sql = """
    INSERT INTO [x].[dbo].[x] ([commcell],[clientName],[clientDisplayName],[clientHostName],[instanceId]) "
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) 
"""

count = cursor.execute(sql,
    client['commcell'], 
    client['clientName'], 
    client['clientDisplayName'], 
    client['clientHostName'], 
    client['instanceId'])
...
```

It's also possible to insert multiple rows at a time using `executemany` and setting `cursor.fast_executemany = True` :

```
cursor.fast_executemany = True
..
tuples=[('foo','bar', 'ham'), ('hoo','far', 'bam')]
cursor.executemany(sql, tuples)
cursor.commit()
```

This caches all values in memory and sends all of them at once to the server

Comment: "The parameter values never become part of the query itself" well done for correctly explaining parameterization. So many people have the misconception that *sanitizing* or *escaping* is going on here when it isn't.